# Has Earth's atmosphere lost mass throughout the geological ages due to biological $\small\sf{CO_2}$ fixation?

Tags: atmosphere, geochemistry, earth-history, biogeochemistry

[Stromatolites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stromatolite) and other organisms have been storing $\small\sf{CO_2}$ in the form of $\small\sf{CaCO_3}$ throughout the geological ages, forming extensive limestone deposits scattered across Earth's crust.

Has this $\small\sf{CO_2}$ fixation process reduced significantly atmosphere mass?

Or, as part of a biological cycle, it hasn't changed the quantity of molecules of Earth's atmosphere and has only changed atmosphere composition?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth#Evolution_of_Earth's_atmosphere

Comment: "A similar study in 2016 looked at the size distribution of gas bubbles in basaltic lava flows that solidified at sea level also during the Archean (~2,700 Ma). They found an atmospheric pressure of only 0.23 ± 0.23 bar (23 kPa)" - [Paleoatmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleoatmosphere)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the Earth's atmosphere has thinned in the past few billion years, and biological fixation of CO2 was one of the main causes. It also gave us our present abundance of oxygen (21%). Enormous quantities of CO2 were used in the form of CaCO3 by foraminifera, corals etc to make their hard skeletons, and the resulting sediments formed limestone. Other elements formed compounds with carbonic acid (CO2 + H2O) to create other carbonate rocks.

In addition there is the more obvious sequestration of CO2 which was taken from the atmosphere by photosynthetic organisms and buried underground in the form of fossil hydrocarbons (oil, coal, gas, lignite etc). It was this which gave us our all-important oxygen. So the answer to your question is that biological activity has done both. It has hugely reduced the mass of the Earth's atmosphere, and at the same time greatly altered its composition.

It is also worth noting that the Earth loses substantial quantities of atmospheric gases into space, mostly hydrogen, but other gases as well. The bombardment of the outer atmosphere by ultraviolet rays, cosmic rays and the solar wind plays a part in this.

Comment: Do you know from any paper or text book it has been thinned? [We are starting to ask for citation when concepts are not very basic](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1818/do-we-need-to-be-stricter-on-enforcing-citations)

Comment: It's a matter of common sense that you couldn't remove that much CO2 from the atmosphere without thinning it. Have you any idea of how much CaCO3 there is in the world? It is also known that Earth, Venus and Mars started out with dense CO2 atmospheres, so on Earth where has it all gone? My answer explains. Oxygen is a rare gas in atmospheres which are not altered by biological activity; there's hardly any on Mars and Venus.

Comment: If you remove mass from the atmosphere, it does not have to get thinner: it can also get less dense. That's what my "common sense" tells me...

Comment: Sorry again I was trying to ask about mass, nor pressure nor density. I edited my question to ask for mass. I think and I hoppe this don't change Michael answer meanning.

Comment: Qualitativelly it can be common sense. Biosphere **should** have reduced atmosphere mass because of nature laws. But an answer could include studies about proto-atmosphere mass I don't find by my own. I am not saying your answer is wrong, but I have asked the need sources popup.Also, I wonder about the biogeochemistry behind. Someone could say that CO2 has been mostly transformed into O2. You say both, but you don't explain what happens in the biogeochemical cycle.

Comment: Related to the question, I have searched some info this days about the topic and I don't find any paper saying proto earth atmosphere was similar to present Venus atmosphere. Earth could have less CO2 on his origins.If you find that info, please share it.

Comment: That's not what I said. What I said was that 4 billion years ago these three planets all had similar atmospheres, mainly composed of CO2. I go into details about what happened on Venus in my answer to another question. Runaway greenhouse effect, of course. What happened to Earth's atmosphere I explain in my answer to you. Mars has neither had a runaway greenhouse effect nor biological modification, but owing to its weak gravitational field has lost most of its atmosphere into space. Four billion years is an unimaginably long time.

Comment: And I am asking to you from where did you get or learned or guessed from logic the 3 planets had a similar atmosphere, as I don't find research about that. As you never quote anything who knows if that's true.

Comment: @Universal_learner Michael is arguing from a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority. He has a  high rep  hence he is an authority and we must all listen without questioning him.

Comment: @Universal Learner  When CO2 was split by photosynthesis into O2 and carbon, you are probably wondering what happened to the carbon. It was combined with H2O to form carbohydrates, which became cellulose, then plant material such as  trees etc, and finally coal and hydrocarbons (oil and gas). 21% of the atmosphere is made of O2, and at about 60,000 feet is a thin layer of O3, commonly known as ozone. The words 'carbohydrates' and 'hydrocarbons' give you a clue as to what they're made of.

Comment: I can't provide accurate figures for quantities, and I doubt that anyone can, but two things tell us that the carbon taken from the atmosphere must have been a tremendous amount. One is the amount of limestone and other carbonate rocks, the other is the 21 percent O2 in the atmosphere. There probably is a ball park figure somewhere for the O2 in tons, and it is obvious that to produce this much O2 a staggering amount of CO2 had to be photosynthesised. Remember that not all the O2 is still present in the atmosphere, much of it went to oxidise iron etc in the rocks, where it remains.

Comment: Yes Michael but I am asking somehow quantitativelly if the mass lost is significative. Also the bulk is not a closed system, mantle continues outgassing and there is physical lost of materia out in the space. I know photosynthesis takes the C of a CO2 molecule to create with water hydrocarbons. This differs on foraminifera, as they are heterotrophous amoebes

Comment: Also if your asseveration were true the start of lost mass would be dated on Cambrian. For that I quoted stromatolites but stromatolites create the CaCO3 thanks to cianobacteria. Again needs citation. If you quote a paper that says "Earth atmosphere started to loose mass on Cambrian due to C fixation organisms", I promise you to accept your answer, even you never upvote the questions you answer. [as others do](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/19877/phishmaster)

Comment: You're always putting words into my mouth. That's not what I said. If you read my answer carefully you'll see it says "the last few billion years", which puts it in the early pre-Cambrian, not the Cambrian. I always put my answers in as simple terms as I can, and I can't make it any simpler. It's a question of reading it properly. Maybe English is not your first language. I also say in one of the earlier comments "4 billion years is an unimaginably long time".

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival "thinness" of a gas *means* density.